# Downloading in windows store app throws exception with HResult = 0x80004005

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, comexception, hresult

My windows store application worked fine before, but last time background downloading didn't work. The behaviour is very strange.

Downloading progress works, I can see it on the progress bar.

But at the end there is a `COMException` with message:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
HResult = 0x80004005.`
```

There is a downloaded file in the Downloads folder but with **zero** size. And not only my app has that behaviour. Default email client downloads attachments with zero size in the same way. 
How to fix this? Any idea?

Comment: E_FAIL is only a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting that the Microsoft programmer did, it doesn't tell you what went wrong.  You'll have to putz around to find a possible reason.

Comment: I think it's something with my system. I'm going to try to repair it with install cd...